# Number of ways to choose $3$ squares in a $n$ by $n$ grid given following constraints

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

In how many ways can $3$ squares be chosen from a $n$ by $n$ grid so that no two chosen squares are in the same row or column ?

I figured out that the general formula for the above problem is: $$  \cfrac{\dbinom {n^2}{ 1} \cdot \dbinom {(n-1)^2}{1} \dbinom {(n-2)^2}{1}}{3!}$$ by realizing that whatever square I choose,the next square can be placed in a lower 
$n-1$ by $n-1$ square and so on.

But when I try the following approach I get the wrong answer:

We can choose $3$ distinct places for the squares by choosing distinct rows and columns. For that we can choose $ \dbinom{n}{3}$ rows and $\dbinom {n}{3} $ columns, so we have in total $\dbinom {n}{3} \cdot \dbinom {n}{3} $  ways to perform this task.

However this answer is wrong, and I can't understand what I'm not counting. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your only mistake is not multiplying your second answer by 3! for the number of ways that a row can be linked to a column.

Squares could be in:
$(r_1,c_1) \&(r_2,c_2)\&(r_3,c_3)$ or $(r_1,c_1) \&(r_2,c_3)\&(r_3,c_2)$ or $(r_1,c_2) \&(r_2,c_1)\&(r_3,c_3)$ or $(r_1,c_2) \&(r_2,c_3)\&(r_3,c_1)$ or $(r_1,c_3) \&(r_2,c_1)\&(r_3,c_2)$ or $(r_1,c_3) \&(r_2,c_2)\&(r_3,c_1)$.

$$\cfrac{\dbinom {n^2}{ 1} \cdot \dbinom {(n-1)^2}{1} \dbinom {(n-2)^2}{1}}{3!}= 6\times\dbinom {n}{3} \cdot \dbinom {n}{3} $$

Comment: What do you mean by linking rows and columns ? the squares are indistinguishable.I don't get the meaning of multiplying by $6$.

Comment: You picked 3 row and 3 columns. They are different.